# String or binary data would be truncated error in SQL server. How to know the column name throwing this error

Tags: sql-server

I have an insert Query and inserting data using SELECT query and certain joins between tables. 
While running that query, it is giving error "String or binary data would be truncated".
There are thousands of rows and multiple columns I am trying to insert in that table.
So it is not possible to visualize all data and see what data is throwing this error.
Is there any specific way to identify which column is throwing this error? or any specific record not getting inserted properly and resulted into this error?
I found one article on this:

[RareSQL](https://raresql.com/2014/01/03/sql-server-a-quick-solution-to-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-using-stored-procedure/)

But this is when we insert data using some values and that insert is one by one.
I am inserting multiple rows at the same time using SELECT statements.
E.g.,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (COLUMN1, COLUMN2,..) SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2,.., FROM TABLE2 JOIN TABLE3
```

Also, in my case, I am having multiple inserts and update statements and even not sure which statement is throwing this error.

Comment: Insert into a staging table and check the length of the data in the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a selection like this:

```
select TABLE2.ID, TABLE3.ID TABLE1.COLUMN1, TABLE1.COLUMN2, ...
FROM TABLE2
JOIN TABLE3
ON TABLE2.JOINCOLUMN1 = TABLE3.JOINCOLUMN2
LEFT JOIN TABLE1
ON TABLE1.COLUMN1 = TABLE2.COLUMN1 and TABLE1.COLUMN2 = TABLE2.COLUMN2, ...
WHERE TABLE1.ID = NULL
```

The first `join` reproduces the selection you have been using for the `insert` and the second `join` is a `left join`, which will yield `null` values for `TABLE1` if a row having the exact column values you wanted to `insert` does not exist. You can apply this logic to your other queries, which were not given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might just have to do it the hard way. To make it a little simpler, you can do this

Temporarily remove the insert command from the query, so you are getting a result set out of it. You might need to give some of the columns aliases if they don't come with one. Then wrap that select query as a subquery, and test likely columns (nvarchars, etc) like this

```
Select top 5 len(Col1), *
   from    (Select col1, col2, ... your query (without insert) here) A
Order by 1 desc
```

This will sort the rows with the largest values in the specified column first and just return the rows with the top 5 values - enough to see if you've got a big problem or just one or two rows with an issue. You can quickly change which column you're checking simply by changing the column name in the len(Col1) part of the first line.

If the subquery takes a long time to run, create a temp table with the same columns but with the string sizes large (like varchar(max) or something) so there are no errors, and then you can do the insert just once to that table, and run your tests on that table instead of running the subquery a lot

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but here I don't know which column is causing the issue and there are so many columns. If I write all column names, it is sorting the data by only one column whichever I write first. So how to know which column should I write first?

Comment: You need to try them one by one until you find the one with the problem - that's why I called this the hard way. You should be able to take a good guess at where the problem will be - this error only applies to strings, binaries etc, not numbers. Try the shortest strings first - if you have a phone number, for example, some-one may have a number with an extension or contact that makes it too long. Also try Adinugraha's answer - it looks like it might do it better.

Answer (score 0):

[From this answer](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Dialogs/PostDetails.aspx?PostID=1215309),
you can use temp table and compare with target table.

for example this

```
Insert into dbo.MyTable (columns)
Select columns
from MyDataSource ;
```

Become this

```
Select columns 
into #T
from MyDataSource;

select *
from tempdb.sys.columns as TempCols
full outer join MyDb.sys.columns as RealCols
  on TempCols.name = RealCols.name
  and TempCols.object_id = Object_ID(N'tempdb..#T')
  and RealCols.object_id = Object_ID(N'MyDb.dbo.MyTable)
where TempCols.name is null -- no match for real target name 
or RealCols.name is null -- no match for temp target name
or RealCols.system_type_id != TempCols.system_type_id
or RealCols.max_length < TempCols.max_length ;
```